# Remove Decimal but Keep Values - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data request - SQL Server 2014 (fourth column). The application does not handle decimals. So I have to provide the data without the decimals. For example: If an employee worked 8 hours, I am sending 8.00. The upstream application wants the data as 800. Or if its less than 8 hours then 050 (.50) for half hour.

My calculation for two weeks of work is:

```
CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), dur) / 60 AS HOURS
```

[image]

My question is: how do I strip that decimal yet maintain the correct hours such that 8.00 becomes 800?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: How does less than 8 hours become 050?

Comment: If the employee would have worked, say, 30 minutes during a day or a pay period.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply convert the hours to a string and then replace the decimal with nothing. If necessary, convert the string without the decimal to an integer.

```
DECLARE @Hours DECIMAL(10, 2)

SET @Hours = 8.50

SELECT
  @Hours AS [Hours]
, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @Hours), '.', '') AS [Hours as String]
, CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @Hours), '.', '')) AS [Hours as Integer]
```

Comment: Thank you @isaac. This did guide me in the correct direction. I was able to add the REPLACE function to eliminate the decimal. {REPLACE((CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), dur) / 60),'.','') AS HOURS} I will try to just pick the first three characters next. That will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Since your application is expecting leading zeros on values under an hour, you're going to have to pad that out. However, since there can be values over 10 hours, we need to treat those a little differently to account for the extra characters in the end result.

This seems to give the values you're looking for.

Setup:

```
create table t
    (tm decimal(18,5));

insert t values (8.05999),(11.00000),(0.34111);
```

Query:

```
select 
    case 
        when t.tm > 10 
            then cast(cast(t.tm*100 as integer) as varchar(5)) --<-Handles longer shifts
        else right(concat('000',cast(t.tm*100 as integer)),3)  --<-Handles shorter shifts
    end as appVal
from t;
```

Results:

```
+--------+
| appVal |
+--------+
|    805 |
|   1100 |
|    034 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the decimal sign as suggested by @isaac and @eric-brandt. Then only populated the number of values the upstream application needed.

```
LEFT(REPLACE((CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), dur) / 60),'.',''),3) AS HOURS,
```